# How can I query a database of tables for a specific row value?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm working with a database with ~20 tables, and need to find the table which has a string value 'fees' in it.

How would I go about searching for the table which contains this?

I tried using

```
Select  t.name as table_name, c.name as column_name
from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.tables t 
            on c.object_id=t.object_id
Where c.name like '%fees%'
```

although, obviously, this only returned tables with their respective columns that contained the word 'fees'.

Is there a way to find the table containing row values = 'fees' ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL databases store structured data and therefore one needs to look in the right place in the structure for data sought after.  That said, you can try multiple approaches depending on the total amount of data you have.

1. If the amount of data is relatively small, say a few hundred megabytes up to a gigabyte or so, you can dump each table into a file in text form.  Then you can use a tool like grep to search for the files containing that data.
2. If the amount of data is considerably larger, you can query the system catalog as you did but the form of the queries can be ones that return sql selects as output.  You can then execute those sql selects to see if any of them return what you are looking for.  E.g.

   `select
   'select  ' + c.name + ' from ' + t.name + ' where ' + c.name + ' like ''%fees%'''
   from
   sys.columns as c
       inner join
   sys.tables as t
       on c.object_id=t.object_id
   where
   c.system_type_id in (167, 231) -- Get the rest of these values by inspecting sys.types
   and t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'`

Comment: I tested this on SQL Server but it should work on MySQL though you may have to adjust the second line to accommodate MySQL string concatenation and quote escaping issues.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I will try this now and get back to you.
Thank you kindly!